# Why does windows services show that QuartzServer is not running even when it's running?

Tags: service, windows-services, quartz.net

I have scheduled to run a job everyday at a given time and it does. But when I go to Windows services, it does not show that QuartzServer is in running state.

Is there a command to check whether the QuartzServer is actually running or not?

Comment: Note that the Services.msc window is not automatically refreshed. Does it show the right status after you refresh manually (F5)?

Comment: @CoreTech Even after refreshing manually it does not show as RUNNING. jvilalta's answer below worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can type this from the command line:

```
sc query QuartzServer
```

It will return, among other things, the state of the service.